# Check if user enters negative numbers straight away?

Tags: java, negative-number

I am trying to make a program where the user enters a number and the program computes the max and min and keeps asking untill it encounters negative.

DETAILED DESCRIPTION:-

However if the user enters a negative number at start up it should print "Max and min are undefined!" and end.

But if a positive number is entered the program prints max and min ,still keeps asking for more numbers untill a negative number is encountered ,seeing negative number it still prints max and min and then ends.

Is there a way to do this?

What i have tried is given below:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NegativeNum {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        double num = keys.nextInt();
        double Max = num+0.5;
        double Min = num-0.5;

        if(num<0) {
            System.out.println("Max and Min undefined");
        }

        while(num>0) {
            System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
            System.out.println("Min = " + Min);
            System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");
            num = keys.nextInt();

        }

        {
            num = num*-1;
            System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
            System.out.println("Min = " + Min);
            System.out.println("Number is Negative! System Shutdown!");
            System.exit(1);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If a negative number is entered, should it convert it to a positive number and recompute a new max and min? Or reuse the old max and min?

Comment: @KacyRaye - Yeah so if -5 is entered, it will find the min and max of positive 5

Comment: Should it do the same thing at startup?

Comment: At startup if the user enters a Negative Number straight away - It should print "Max and Min undefined!" and then stop the program

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NegativeNum {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        double num = keys.nextInt();
        double Max = num+0.5;
        double Min = num-0.5;

        if(num<0) {
            System.out.println("Max and Min undefined");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while(true) {     
            double temp_num = num;         

            num = Math.abs(num);
            Max = num+0.5;
            Min = num-0.5;

            System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
            System.out.println("Min = " + Min);

            if ( temp_num < 0 )
                break;

            System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");
            num = keys.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Number is Negative! System Shutdown!");

    }
}
```

Comment: If a Negative Number is entered after a positive number is entered - it should print the max and min of the negative number - how does it do that then - its not doing it currently

Comment: That contradicts your comment from earlier: `Yeah so if -5 is entered, it will find the min and max of positive 5.`

Please clarify.
I edited my answer so it guarantees the number is positive and then computes the max and min based on the positive number.

Comment: If at Startup of the program a negative Number is entered the program should print "Max and Min undefined". However if the user enters a positive number first it will keep asking for a number and if a negative number is entered - then it should print the max and min - Its only at startup it should print that.

Comment: @Mathematica Okay so the max and min is only computed once in the beginning, and only gets printed out for negative numbers?

Comment: No - Max and min will be computed as long as user enters a positive number, it will keep the user to input a number. If at the start a negative number is entered it prints "Max and min undefined", if a positive number is entered then an Negative number is entered it will computer max and min of the number(ignoring the negative) and then will stop

Comment: Okay I edited it.  If the first thing a user enters is a negative number, the program stops.  If a user enters a positive number first, the programs keeps asking for more numbers.  If the numbers are then positive or negative, the Max and Min are recomputed, but the program stops if the number is negative.
Sound right?

Comment: @Mathematica I had 2 syntax errors that I corrected, but yeah it works now.  Now accept my answer so I'm not stuck with `666` as my reputation lol.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the maximum and minimum value during iteration

```
while(num>0) {
    System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
    System.out.println("Min = " + Min);
    System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");
    num = keys.nextInt();
    if(Math.abs(num) > max) {
        max = Math.abs(num);
    } 
    if(Math.abs(num) < min) {
        min = Math.abs(num);
    }  
}

System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
System.out.println("Min = " + Min);
System.out.println("Number is Negative! System Shutdown!");
System.exit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NegativeNum {
    private static int entryCount = 0;  // Count the Number of Entries

    public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        double num = keys.nextInt();
        double Max = num+0.5;
        double Min = num-0.5;


        while(true) {
            if( num < 0 && entryCount == 0) { // Make sure if it's first entry and it's negative too
                System.out.println("Number is Negative! System Shutdown!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
            System.out.println("Min = " + Min);
            System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");
            num = keys.nextInt();
            entryCount++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code successfully runs all the cases:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class class2 
{


        public void positive(double num)
        {
         double Max = num+0.5;
         double Min = num-0.5;

             System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
             System.out.println("Min = " + Min);
             System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");


        }

        public void negative(double num,String k)
            {

            double Max = num+0.5;
            double Min = num-0.5;
            System.out.println("Max = " + Max);
            System.out.println("Min = " + Min);


               if(k=="terminate")
               {
                 System.out.println("System is shutting down");
                 System.exit(1);
               }
            System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");

       }

public static void main(String []args) 
{

    class2 obj=new class2();
    Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    boolean bol=true;
    String k="";
    double num = keys.nextInt();
    int count=1;
    if(num<0 && count ==1) 
    {
       k="terminate";
       count=count+1;

       System.out.println("Max and Min undefined");
       System.exit(1);
       System.out.println("\nEnter another: ");
       num = keys.nextInt();

    }

    while(bol==true)
    {
    while(num>0) 
    {
           count=count+1;
           obj.positive(num);
           num = keys.nextInt();


    }
    while(num<0 && count!=2)
    {
         k="terminate";
         obj.negative(num,k);
         num = keys.nextInt();
    }
    count=count+1;
    }

}
}
```